# bash sed replacing text with regex

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file named package.json that contains the following snippit:

```
  "single-instance":true,
  "user-agent": "somename",
  "PORT": 2000,
```

I need to replace 'somename' with another value (in this case xxx) and 'somename' is not fixed, it could be anything.

So I have tried using the following regex however it's not updating the file.

I have tested the regex expression on regex101 and it appears to be valid so I guess it must be something to do with the sed syntax ??

```
    sed -i 's/"user-agent": "(.*)"/xxx/' package.json
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong ?

Comment: note that by default sed uses BRE where `()` are not meta characters... you need to use `\(\)` or activate ERE with sed's `-E` or `-r` option.. see http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html for BRE/ERE

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the matched key and use back-reference in replacement:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/("user-agent": )"[^"]*"/\1"xxx"/' file

cat file

"single-instance":true,
"user-agent": "xxx",
"PORT": 2000,
```

Take note of `(` and `)` around `"user-agent":` for capturing the value in group #1 and use `\1` in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this after backup package.json

```
sed -i -re 's/("user-agent":).*$/\1 "xxx"/' package.json
```